# I'm trying to add firebase to my flutter project but i keep on getting this Error Could not find method implementation()

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

```
**This is the error message :** 

Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\HP-LinkR\Videos\event_notifier\android\build.gradle' 
 line: 35

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Could not find method implementation() for arguments
```

[com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0] on object of type

org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

```
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or -- 
debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2s
Exception: Gradle task assembly debug failed with exit code 1



***This is code for the Build.gradle file that is giving the error:***
    New Properties methods is highlighted red
```

***This is code for the Build.gradle file that is giving the error:***
New Properties methods is highlighted red
***This is code for the Build.gradle file that is giving the error:***
New Properties methods is highlighted red

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with 
flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID 
  (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
         applicationId "com.example.event_notifier"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName

        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run -- 
release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib- 
jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Comment: can you briefly describe what steps you followed?

Comment: I follow the steps on the firebase website > Firebase displayed all the steps to do the integration, but what I found weird is that as soon as I opened the build. Gradle file the error popped up.

Comment: https://ibb.co/QDdBB9s   this a link to my directory

Answer (score 0):

Goto `event_notifier\android\build.gradle` ...

These `dependencies` should make it build:

```
dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib- 
jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2"
    compile "com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1"
}
```

The actual problem seems to be a quite outdated version of the Android Gradle Plugin.

You'd have to upgrade to something more current to use `implementation`:

```
classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"
```

And maybe already start with current `androidx` packages ...because else you'll be stuck at the latest version of Firebase libraries, which use these **obsolete** support libraries. That Flutter project may generally be outdated and might require some refactoring (unless using the above `compile`):

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.72"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.4"

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.multidex/multidex
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
}
```